# Table design for linking pictures to a place

Tags: database-design, table

Could someone give me some advice on designing a table for a system that has to store
x picture for 1 place?

Is it better to have something like this:

place table:

```
id_place / reference
100           1
200           2
300           3

picture table:
id_picture / reference / picture_url / main_piture
1               1            xxx           false
2               1            xxx           true
3               1            xxx           false
4               2            xxx           false
5               2            xxx           true
6               3            xxx           false
7               3            xxx           true
8               3            xxx           false
```

Or is it better to have it all in one table?

```
picture table:
id_picture / id_place / picture_url / main_picture
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first option, will there be a one-to-one between `id_place` and `reference`?  If so then it adds no value.  Instead, it will complicate your SQL and may make for a less efficient query plan.  The `reference` should be omitted and your second suggestion is the way to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see there is much more difference in the design and given the choice I would choose to have a single table to store these picture.

Single table removes the need to have JOIN in sql query and will improve the performance.

In a single table structure you can create Indexes depending on your sql query used to read data that will improve the performance too.